# VBA If statements with public variables error type mismatch (error 13)

Tags: vba, if-statement, global-variables, public

I think this is probably a quick fix but its been stumping me all morning.

I have defined many variables as public at the top of the vba project (any variables ending in "yn" are String, and the rest are Variant or Single).  Different subs throughout the project define these variables through series of questions and answers.  Now at the end when I try to compile the defined variables into an equation, I'm getting an error.

I already did this same process with a different final equation last week and it worked fine.  I've checked over each variable to make sure that it is correctly entered and I can't see anything wrong with the code.  Please help!  Thanks!

```
    Public Sub Rth1 ()

    Dim Red1th as single

    If Width1thyn = vbYes Then
        If Length1thyn = vbYes Then
            If V1turnspeedyn = vbYes Then
                Red1th = ((Width1th + 20) / (1.47 * 20)) - 1
            Else
                Red1th = ((Width1th + 20) / (1.47 * V1turnspeedstudy)) - 1
            End If
        Else
            If V1turnspeedyn = vbYes Then
                Red1th = ((Width1th + Length1thstudy) / (1.47 * 20)) - 1
            Else
                Red1th = ((Width1th + Length1thstudy) / (1.47 * V1turnspeedstudy)) - 1
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If Length1thyn = vbYes Then
            If V1turnspeedyn = vbYes Then
                Red1th = ((Width1thstudy + 20) / (1.47 * 20)) - 1
            Else
                Red1th = ((Width1thstudy + 20) / (1.47 * V1turnspeedstudy)) - 1
            End If
        Else
            If V1turnspeedyn = vbYes Then
                Red1th = ((Width1thstudy + Length1thstudy) / (1.47 * 20)) - 1
            Else
                Red1th = ((Width1thstudy + Length1thstudy) / (1.47 * V1turnspeedstudy)) - 1
            End If
        End If
    End If

    MsgBox "Red Clearance Interval is " & Red1th, "vbOkOnly", "Red Clearance Interval"

    End Sub
```

Comment: `vbYes` is **6**. If your `...yn` data type is a string, then you may get some strange results on comparison. Have you tried `Option Explicit` to ensure you have no spelling mistakes?

Comment: I tried converting all of my "yn" variables back to Integer instead of string, but it didn't change anything.  I also just added Option Explicit, and it didn't find anything.  I'm still getting the same error and now the other final equation that was working previously isn't working either.

Comment: If something isn't working when using Option Explicit, then you haven't `Dim`med the variable anywhere. If the program is failing on the equations, I would check to see what the variables are defined as. `vartype` should help you find out what [type of data](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/vartype-function-HA001228932.aspx) a variable is expecting/using

Comment: What line creates the error?

Answer (score 0):

`vbYes` is used when returning from `MsgBox`.

If your variables don't depend on `MsgBox` returns, consider using `Boolean`or assign then your own enumeration (avoiding using `vb` started names),

or

Get sure that that you use `vbYes` in assignements in previous code.